# Programmatical Function Definition: How to get rid of "eval" here?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a set of functions named "ip", "date", "url" etc.

With these, I want to generate another set of functions "ip-is", "date-is" etc.

I finally have the following solution, thats working fine, but that uses "eval".

```
(loop for name in '(ip date url code bytes referer user-agent) do
  (let ((c-name (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name name) "-IS"))))
    (eval `(defun ,c-name (c)
           #'(lambda (l) (equal (,name l) c))))))
```

Can someone help me, how to get rid of the "evil eval"? It is essential for my program that the function names are provided as a list. So a call to some marcro

```
   (define-predicate ip)
   (define-predicate date)
   (define-predicate url)
```

etc.

would not fit my needs. I have no real problem with "eval", but I read very often, that eval is considered bad style and should be avoided if possible.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a macro here. Macros are evaluated during compile (or load) and can be used to programatically generate a function definition. Your code could be written something like this:

```
(defmacro define-predicates (&rest names)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop
          for name in names
          collect (let ((c-sym (gensym))
                        (l-sym (gensym)))
                    `(defun ,(intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name name) "-IS")) (,c-sym)
                       #'(lambda (,l-sym) (equal (,name ,l-sym) ,c-sym)))))))


(define-predicates ip date url)
```

Note that the symbols are generated using `GENSYM` in the functions. In this particular case, that's not strictly necessary, but I usually prefer to do it this way just so that there is no chance of having any leaking if I were to refactor the code at a later stage.

Comment: Definitely the right case for macros. Using `eval` as the right choice is a very rare case.

Comment: @Elias, just a question about what you wrote:  it seems to me macros can't be evaluated at load time since they are used at compile time to generate code.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a function (instead of a macro as in the other answer), you should be using [`(setf fdefinition)`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm):

```
(loop for name in '(ip date url code bytes referer user-agent) do
  (let ((c-name (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name name) "-IS"))))
    (setf (fdefinition c-name)
          (lambda (c) (lambda (l) (equal (funcall name l) c))))))
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly, what I am looking for, but for some reason, it does not work for me.  I understand the solution but I could not figure out, why its not working. I am using sbcl 1.0.58

Comment: it compiles and if i call (code-is "200") it gives me a predicate closure.  So long everything is fine. But if I call it with my filter routine, it does not match the case correctly when the function "code" delivers "200".  If I call it directy, eg. (defun code (z) "200"), then run your definition, then (funcall   (code-is "200") "200") it breaks with "INVALID-ARRAY-INDEX-ERROR". Thats rather strange, since we are not dealing with arrays here.

Comment: @Patrick: just tested it with sbcl 1.0.55.0; works just fine; `(funcall (code-is "200") "200")` returns `T`.

Comment: I've usually seen 'symbol-function used in this case instead of 'fdefinition. Looking at Clozure's src, the only difference is that fdefinition allows its argument to evaluate to a non symbol. Not sure what that use case is exactly. So 'symbol-function would work in this case, and in all cases that I can think of. Let me know if you can think of a use case where the arg to fdefinition is not a symbol.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley: `(fdefinition '(setf foo))` is the only non-symbol.